# Access DB corrupting constantly

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, corruption

I have a Access DB which is a split DB! The back end is on a network folder and the 3 front end are in each one hard disk (not shortcut). All the users have the MS Access 2010 and the DB was develop in MS Access 2010 too.

The back end is getting corrupted constantly. And i can't figure out what's the problem.

I've already C&R, it resolved but i had some data loss, and after a while (30 min) it get corrupted again.

I've already imported all the tables into a new DB, and after a while it still getting corrupted.

I've already imported all the forms, queries, vba, macros, etc. into a new file, and did it with each front end, and it after a while still getting corrupted.

I've compiled the VBA code and it got no error.

I've deleted the Primary Key and re-insert a autonumber field and it still didn't work.

The corruption happens everytime in a specific table

Sometimes I get duplicated entries (which I delete using the duplicate query wizard), sometimes I get "Record is deleted", sometimes i get only ######.

I don't know what else to do! It's driving me crazy!

Comment: It is very hard to pin point, why the corruption occurs. I would suggest you drop the DELETE queries. Instead, create a code that will check the table before adding records to the table. Prevention is better than cure ! Constant delete and read on the tables is likely to cause corruption, specially when these two actions are performed hand in hand.

Comment: @PaulFrancis do you have any code example I can use? Ty

Comment: Does the corruption occur if there is only one user in the database? This means that NONE of the others even open the database. Usually the issue (in a multi-user environment) is due to how updates/adds/deletes are programmed. How reliable is your network connection? Any blips?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn the corruption occurs when the three users uses the database. The main user adds the records to the table and the other two just insert the rest of the information in the record that already exists. I redid all the macros and VBA code and update all the forms with a "edited record" in the RecordLocks properties. Set to No the AllowDelete properties in all forms and No to the AllowAdd and AllowEditting properties in the forms that don't need this actions. So far so good. Let's see what's happen.

Comment: Hopefully your changes solve the issue. Years ago we encountered similar issues as you have now, but not as frequent. In some cases the culprit was a faulty network, sometimes by users powering down (and I don't mean gracefully). If the issue returns, you may want to look at the following link - it provides a good explanation of why/when to change settings for locking.  Good Luck!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672077/setting-up-an-ms-access-db-for-multi-user-access