# Microsoft Access: Can't create a database web app, client still wants us to use it

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm a college senior in CS and I am currently part of a new intern project where there's only me and one other intern so it's a fairly small scale project with just two programmers. So we just realized today that we cannot create a web application as originally intended, but then after our project manager discussed with our 'client' of what she expects, she still wants it to be done in Access, even with this new limitation. To their knowledge, it is still doable to just continue creating what we have so far, (we've just done random features so far, only just finalized the task board, it's all very messy) and then later just share the read-only version as an .accdr file into a shared folder drive. There will be limited permissions and such, but I am still unsure. I will definitely continue my research and do what we can, but I'd like to know what other people think. Is it still possible to just create a shared read-only version of a database? What kind of limitations would you expect as opposed to a web application?

It's an event planner where it should contain all the tables of data, a search interface, a planning interface (which will also prompt for a planner sign in for those who should have rights to do so), and a results page.

Prior to this position, I've never worked with Access before considering that my school is mostly about programming languages and then all the other fields of Networking, Linux, OS, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are several possible ways to accomplish such a thing. It's all a matter of the reason to do so. For instance, if you're running a back-end attached to the Access Database as a front-end, simply disseminating copies of an Access Database to the end-user would successfully accomplish this goal, as long as there was no direct way for them to modifiy anything on the back-end that you did not allow. If the purpose is to only read data, it can accomplish that with forms, etc. The basic idea, is its too much to answer here, but if you have a more specific question, we can help with that.

Comment: @Jiggles32 The purpose is for most users to be able to read the data, but only a good handful can log in as a planner and add in and/or edit some event information.

Comment: You may want to check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672077/setting-up-an-ms-access-db-for-multi-user-access